# Term for pronunciation technique

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes there are words that are foreign, and a bit hard for anglophones to articulate. Such as "Dvorak", or "dvelja". When trying to refer to these words in our conversation, sometimes an extra vowel is added between the two consonants, so that it is easier to pronounce. For example, "Dvorak" is pronounced "D-ə-vo-zhak". Also, "bdellium" is pronounced "b-ə-de-llium"

Is there actually a term for this addition of vowel?

Comment: >> "we tend to add an extra vowel between the two consonants" -- Who is "we" and what vowel is being added between which consonants? I normally don't add any vowels to "Dvorak". Can you substantiate that claim and provide a few samples?

Comment: Actually, what raised the question was when I heard "Dvorak" pronounced on the radio like that, except it was done rather quickly.

Comment: @z7sg, I understand that what I put up there isn't actually the correct pronounciation, but that is what people sometimes do. I'm just using it as an example.

Comment: OK, just as a note because laziness about foreign names is a pet hate of mine Dvorak is pronounced /ˈdvɔrʒɑːk/ (dvor-ZHAK).

Comment: I've edited the question so that the last syllable should be pronounced correctly :)

Comment: @z7sg: Er ... no it isn't. "ř" represents a single sound, not the sequence /rʒ/

Comment: @Colin Fine Er, true but it is impossible for English people to pronounce ř without some training... this is the closest you can get. Arguably better without the /r/ though I can't edit it now.

Comment: @z7sg -- I'm confused: why do you perceive it as a problem that English speakers avoid a stress pattern not native to English, but not that they alter phoneme types that are not native to English?

Comment: @Neil Coffey Btw, in case you missed the original edit, it was written de-vor-ak. And there is nothing unfamiliar about the stress pattern, only the combination of those two particular consonants.  I don't see the difficulty there.  It reminded me of a man I heard on the radio yesterday talking about Friedrich 'Neet-shee'.  I just expect someone speaking in front of an audience of thousands to actually bother to make sure they pronounce peoples' names correctly... is that too much to expect?

Comment: @z7sg - and it depends on the person, Dvorak the composer is pronounced vor-zhak, Dvorak the political pundit is d-vor-ack. Particularly a problem in America, you pronounce someones name properly (as it would be in German,French,etc) and they look at you like your an idiot, pronounce someone else's in English and they are offended!

Comment: @Martin Hmmm yes that is a problem.  Even for a common name like Braun. (brawn or brown?)

Comment: @z7sg - But permitted stress is dependent on the phonemes in question!

Comment: @Neil Coffey I don't understand at all what you mean by 'permitted'.  There is no stress rule in English, the stress forms part of the word itself and can distinguish between what would otherwise be homophones.

Comment: @z7sg - That's not quite true: there are actually patterns in English as to where the stress would tend to go. The patterns are quite complex, so for the sake of simplicity, it's common for learners to just to learn by rote which syllable is stressed. But to a native speaker encountering a word for the first time, there are strong tendencies to "automatically" place the stress on a particular syllable depending on the phonemic content of the word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called **[epenthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis)**.

> In phonology, epenthesis
>   (/əˈpɛnθəsɪs/, Ancient Greek ἐπένθεσις
>   - epenthesis, from epi "on" + en "in" + thesis "putting") is the addition of one or more sounds to a word,
>   especially to the interior of a word.

Answer (score 0):

Another term for this vowel is "shewa" or "schwa", from the Hebrew vowel system. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa